# Strange directory permission behavior in docker container

Tags: docker

I'm seeing some strange behavior in a docker container running Ubuntu 16.04 (the system it's running on is also running that OS). A directory appears to be readable/searchable by all but `ls -l` fails with "permission denied".

```
# docker exec f26498a91394 ls -l /var/lib/cassandra
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra 154 Sep 25 18:49 commitlog
drwxr-xr-x 12 cassandra cassandra 213 Sep 25 18:42 data
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   6 Sep 19 22:33 hints
drwxr-xr-x  2 cassandra cassandra   6 Sep 19 22:33 saved_caches
# docker exec f26498a91394 ls -l /var/lib/cassandra/data
ls: cannot open directory '/var/lib/cassandra/data': Permission denied
```

That directory is not a mount point. What could cause this behavior?

Comment: Is it part of docker "volume"? If so, what's the underlying storage?

Comment: This turned out to be a kernel (or docker) bug. The problem doesn't happen if the host is running 18.04.

Comment: feel free to post that as an answer.